# how to set simple validation on material design textbox in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, material-design

i have used all these methods INotifyDataError , validatioOnException , validation Rules and its all working ..

```
<TextBox x:Name="MobileTextBox" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Mobile" ></TextBox>
<Button Click="onClick"><Button/>
onClick(){
   MobileTextBox.HasAnError = true ;
   MobileTextBox.ErrorMessage = "Mobile no. not found"
}
```

but is there a simple way to handle error something like above in wpf for materialdesign textbox validation

Answer (score 0):

> but is there a simple way to handle error something like above in wpf for materialdesign textbox validation

No, I am afraid not.

You actually need to hook into the WPF validation engine by implementing `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, `IDataErrorInfo` or validation rules.

The material design library just provides a custom validation error *template*. The validation *funtionality* is not customized.